# Starting New Project in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm new to android studio. I've imported source codes of some apps to android studio to learn. and then I started to practice by creating a new project. when new project created It doesn't show the default main activity and xml instead It showed many existing activities and xml of the existing project. I've tried to create new project a few times but it's still the same. thought that I might make some mistakes somewhere. I don't know. Please kindly help. thank beforehand !

Comment: start a new project with empty activity

Comment: If you are new too android than you can start tutorial following by android developer official website from here https://developer.android.com/courses?gclid=CjwKCAjwxo6IBhBKEiwAXSYBsxMkFwaS2EPQW0aF6MzqS-2_b5gfAqEK2KBoejxGSGECG7mAfdMffRoCWx8QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds you find some code labs in Java and kotlin from scratch like starting from installing android studio to creating new project .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a simple app on Android Studio what you have to do is to choose the Empty Activity.
[image]

Then you add the name to your app, choose the location, choose the language to program (Java/Kotlin), the minimum SDK (use the recommended one to start) and hit Finish. It should create one simple activity with one layout which shows a `TextView` with Hello World! as a text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some screenshots? It would make it easier to help you :)

For the moment, I would suggest that you make sure that you're selecting "blank activity" when you create it. Also check that you've stored your downloaded source code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio remembers last opened project. The next time you start Android Studio, it will open last opened project.

You can choose menu File -> Close Project. Then it goes back to open/new screen which allows you to create your own project.

Answer (score 0):

ah it was a silly mistake guys. I confused to click on basic activity instead of empty activity. thank you guys so much !