# New project in Android Studio does not show basic code and does not create java file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm new to Java coding and to Android studio. After selecting to create a new project, I select the option "Empty Activity" and then Java as the language. I essentially follow all the "newby" steps, as described, say, here in the first answer: [Starting New Project in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68587172/starting-new-project-in-android-studio)

When I press finish, I get the following screen:
[image]

EDIT: The directory in which Android studio is installed is contained within a User folder that contains a space (it can't be renamed). This might be a source of problems (I don't know). I also tried saving the projects in folder C, not in a subfolder contained within C, but this solves nothing (Android Studio was not installed in said folder).

I've read that upon successfully creating such a new project, I should get a screen with some basic code on it. I get nothing like this. I also read that Android studio should create an xml file and a .java file. The .java file is missing.

What's going wrong here? Where can I start writing code? How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you select "Empty Activity"? Or "No Activity"?

Comment: @JornRigter Empty Activity, yes

Comment: What happens if you create a "Basic Activity"? Still an empty project?

Comment: @JornRigter just tried it, it's still empty. I will update the question in a bit to include a few more details that can be helpful.

Comment: Very strange. Maybe you could try completely uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Its look like your project is not created properly, If you create new project in android studio it will look like as below SS.
[image]

You can also check your project folder and file from finder option like below SS.
[image]

After that you can see below structure for your project
[image]

You don't found anything like above SS please try to create another project but this time change your location for your project.

One more thing in Android Kotlin is more preferable over JAVA so also check with Kotlin for development.

Good Luck!!.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried creating another project in a different location, but it didn't work either. Moreover, in your second screenshot, on the left of the code with the list with the 3 options, I do not have the first option, so I don't even have an option for the finder. Maybe I'm missing something? For example, I only downloaded Android Studio, but I never did anything concerning Java, so I might need to install something related to Java? A .java file is not created upon the creation of a new project; only an xml file.

Comment: Ok got it, check this link for your JDK location 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608742/how-to-set-java-sdk-path-in-androidstudio]
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Just a quick question: I installed Android studio, and then in a separate directory the JDK. Does this affect anything? Also, do I have to install SDK?

Comment: Does the JDK path affect anything? I get the feeling that by installing Android Studio and then Java, I might have botched up the whole thing

Comment: 1)JDK in separate directory-> not a problem you have to give proper path (I am using mac and I have jdk in library folder)

2)Need to install SDK-> Yes we need SDK 

3)JDK path affect anything-> If you properly provided path in android studio then it not create any problem.